# Check, if a variable is null in a view

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

The following is a code segment from `person.gsp`

```
<g:set var="res" value="${ Person.get(personInstance.id) }" />
                            ${ res.result }
```

I get the following error message.

```
Cannot get property 'result' on null object
```

How can i do a validation to check if `result` is `null` from the `view` itself ?

Note: I don't want to do this validation from the `controller`

UPDATE

Can i do a

```
<g:if........${ Person.get(personInstance.id) } NOT EQUAL TO NULL THEN
<g:set var="res" value="${ Person.get(personInstance.id) }" />
                                ${ res.result }
```

Kind of a thing ? If so how to do it ?

Comment: "Given this really bad premise, how do I make it a little less bad?" Not exactly the Stack Overflow mission statement or canonical question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that you have a **Safe Navigation** operator in Groovy - **?.**

If you type:

```
${res?.result}
```

it will avoid NPE and simply stop further evaluation if res is null. I is also a good practice to call Person.get(id) in the controller and set the result in the model you're associating with view. It will allow you to change your controller behaviour (e.g. reading from cache instead of database) without changing your view.

Answer (score -1):

```
<g:if test="${Person.get(personInstance.id) != null}">
    <g:set var="res" value="${ Person.get(personInstance.id) }" />
    ${ res.result }
</g:if>
```

This worked.

Comment: at least use the set first and then do the check.  even if the getter is most likely cached there from hibernate, DRY